# getelementbyid more parameters

Tags: javascript, pdf, getelementbyid, selectors-api

I'm working on a project and I need to show/hide several pdfs on html page.
This is the part at  which the pdf is shown (on click show and hide other pdf)

It acts fine with 2 pdfs.
But I need to hide more than one pdf at the time. For example:

on click: Laplace.pdf shows up, while Fourier.pdf AND Z.pdf AND integral.pdf must hide of. And so on...

I see the thing is at the <<`var hide = document.getElementById('test');`>> but i can't make getelementbyID work for more IDs. I tried to make it with document.querySelectorAll, but it doesn't work.

Here is a portion of my HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="var id = document.getElementById('test'); var hide = document.getElementById('test2'); if(id.style.display == 'block'){ id.style.display = 'none'; id.style.visibility = 'hidden'; }else{ id.style.display = 'block'; id.style.visibility = 'visible';  hide.style.display = 'none'; hide.style.visibility = 'hidden';}" value="preview pdf" class="button"/>

<embed src="laplace.pdf" style="WIDTH:60%; HEIGHT:500; display:none;  visibility: hidden;" id="test" name="test">
```

Any help would be really thankful.

Comment: It's easy just post your HTML! How does the IDs look like? Is there another way to select the PDF elements without using the IDs?

Comment: There is a lot of different ways to select elements. Here is a list of all [**CSS Selectors**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)!

Comment: I'm really new at these things. I'm working on a project, and this one really gets my frustrated. I don't know any other way to select this particular option (this "name" of the pdf)... it's not a css thing. I think it's a javascript concept of right programming with getelementbyid or document.querySelectorAll, but I can't make it. The css selectors, seems that doesn't work with this concept...

Comment: It could be absolutely solved with `css`, could you try to show more `<embed>`s with each one different name and an example of _query_ you want to do to _filter_? The `id` MUST be unique per element [(more)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) so you think to call each element by its own `id` and filter with another params depending in what your program needs.

Comment: The IDs are allready unique. It does work woth 2 pdfs: the 1st is shown up and the 2nd is hiden. But the 1st on can't make any other to hide, because "getelementbyid" can only get 1 parameter. I'll try to make it with css, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the whole answer to be using jQuery. You have to:

1. Add a class `pdf` on all the `embed` element of the pdfs (`class="pdf"`).
2. Add a data attribute on the buttons to contain the equivalent ID (`data-pdf="test"` ...). And remove the `onclick` property it won't be needed.
3. And of course add the CSS for the class `hidden`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("embed.pdf").addClass("hidden");       // on load, hide all pdfs

  $("[data-pdf]").click(function() {       // when clicking an element with the attribute data-pdf (the buttons)
    var id = $(this).data("pdf");          // get the value of that data-pdf attribute (which is the id of the pdf element to show or hide)
    $this = $('#' + id);                   // get the pdf element itself using that id
    if ($this.hasClass("hidden")) {        // if the element is hidden
      $("embed.pdf").addClass("hidden");   // then hide all other pdfs
      $this.removeClass("hidden");         // and show it
    } else {                               // otherwise
      $this.addClass("hidden");            // hide it
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

embed {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" data-pdf="test" value="show test" />
<input type="button" data-pdf="other" value="show other" />
<input type="button" data-pdf="something" value="show something" />

<embed src="test.pdf" id="test" name="test" class="pdf">
<embed src="pdf.pdf" id="other" name="other" class="pdf">
<embed src="yet another.pdf" id="something" name="something" class="pdf">
```

Comment: Nice concept, but doesn't seem to work. The pdfs are all shown up at the same moment.

Comment: Did you included the CSS for the class `.hidden`??

Comment: @Virmosa weird! It should work! When you said they are all shown at the same moment, did you meant at the start?

Comment: Yes. On the reload of the page, they are all shown like it's by default.

Comment: Also, the do not togle on click.

Comment: @Virmosa that because you didn't add the class `.hidden` like I did. If you want to automatically add it on load I'll update, I'll add the toggling as well!

Comment: I've included the class hidden. Don't know how to make this work, really. Really thank you for the sulurion, though. It's something that will help in other parts, I'm sure! :)

Comment: @Virmosa I updated my answer hope it'll work now! One note though set the onclick of the buttons with a valid ID (`onclick="show('valid ID here')"`)

Comment: I made all the changes. I restarted my Apache. Nothing happened. I've got the class on the right position. Don't know what's going on. Anyway. Doesn't matter. I'll cry alone in my corner :P 

I really really thank you for your help!

Comment: @Virmosa what browser are you testing this on? Is jquery allowed?

Comment: I'm on chrome, and JQ is allowed. I've run many JQ scenarios before.

Comment: @Virmosa I changed the answer to use jQuery. Now it have to work. If you are dynamically generating the buttons then tell me because the event listeners won't work!

Comment: FINALY! IT DOES WORK! I really thank you! Hope you'll be fine! :)